# Add AppClips to ReactNative - how to handle errors

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I'm trying to add AppClips to my React Native project. (`"react-native": "0.66.3"`)

I added new target:

```
target 'Clip' do 
  pod 'React', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
end
```

and I added AppClip in project. Created Bridging file to access ObjectiveC libraries for React Native and inside of `ViewControle` made following:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {

//        let jsCodeLocation = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index.clip.ios", fallbackResource: nil)

        let jsCodeLocation: URL!;
            jsCodeLocation = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index.clip.ios", fallbackResource: nil);
        
        
            let rootView = RCTRootView(
                bundleURL: jsCodeLocation!,
                moduleName: "AppClip",
                initialProperties: nil,
                launchOptions: nil)
            rootView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1)

        
            view = rootView

        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

All is working fine, except It's not sending errors to emulator and I'm getting an error inside of AppDelegate:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this? (I'm not Swift dev, so maybe you'll give me detailed instructions)

Thanks a  lot in advance!

Comment: You may find this useful https://adapptor.com.au/blog/creating-an-apple-app-clip-with-react-native

Comment: Very interesting but nothing mentioned what is catching errors in Emulator. Thanks